# How to Iterate SAP Table and click Each Row Using Excel with UIPATH?

Tags: uipath

I have sap table i want to iterate each row and click the row using Excel in UiPath.
How can i do that can anyone explain briefly.
the tables are differant but it looks same scenario.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 3):

Consider this free resource as your starting point for learning how to automate SAP: [UiPath Academy](https://academy.uipath.com/learn)
After you will finish the foundation course you may try [SAP-specific course](https://academy.uipath.com/learn/course/internal/view/elearning/10/rpa-developer-sap-automation-training) to learn how do solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i can give you a good starter answer
note, i usually just convert all the data to datatable and work with that since i am more familiar, but you can use the excel activities and click features

**1st**. set the activity "*excel application scope*"  that was my hangup forever, and seems to be that first thing that sticks everyone. it focuses all the other excel activities afterwards.

after this use a for each loop the following will show you how to do that easily 
 https://forum.uipath.com/t/loop-something-x-number-of-times/24667

then you can use read/write row/cell/column etc and use the 'i' integer counter to go through each row.

an alternative to the above is to set the excel scope, then read the entire sheet to a datatable, which i find easier if you are just doing database manipulation

also I also would like to double down on llya Kochetov's suggestions of the academy and also the UIPath forum which is incredibly helpful